# Search Api Autocomplete doesnt filter by language

Tags: search, ajax

We're using [Search API Autocomplete](https://drupal.org/project/issues/search_api_autocomplete) with [Search API 7.x-1.9](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) on a site set up with Solr (Websolr) serving nodes in both English and German.

I'm looking to be able to filter the results by ss_search_api_language field which is presently not happening and as such i get autocomplete results for all both languages.

What would be the correct approach to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by fons vandamme via the drupal module issue tracker

```
function filter_by_language_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  //if query is of type search_api_autocomplete we will add our extra language filter
  if (strpos($query->getOption('search id'), 'search_api_autocomplete:') !== false) {
      dsm($query->getOption('search id'));


      global $language;


      $filter = $query->createFilter('AND');
      $filter->condition('language', $language->language, '==');
      $query->filter($filter);


  }
}
```

Make sure the language of your nodes are in the index.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2166113

Comment: Nice answer but it should be '=' and not '=='.