# how to alter view query to run over translated content done with lingotek D7 module?

Tags: 7, search

I have a Multilanguage site done over [Lingotek D7 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/lingotek), has enabled [search_api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), [search_api_autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_autocomplete) and solr. While typing text in autocomplete, query runs over original node (uploaded in x language) and I need to run it over the translated content when site is viewed in another language.

I have tried this solution without luck. 
[Search Api Autocomplete doesnt filter by language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98713/search-api-autocomplete-doesnt-filter-by-language)

please point me (I hope with some code) how I can alter (view?) query?

Comment: did you make sure you index the language of the content? Otherwise the fix that I suggested on drupal.org won't work.

Comment: Thank you fOns, yes I had checked index language, my problem was that I had enebleled in index to load source node, now is working.